# Gallery being cut on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to make the gallery on the left fixed and 100% height when it reaches a specific point on scroll. It's currently fixed but seems that the bottom of the image is being cut as you scroll.

[Live example](http://www.warface.co.uk/beta/?p=7)

[image]

Comment: So.... your question is?

Comment: in you example i have not noticed anything bad

Comment: How do I stop the bottom of the image being cut?

Comment: I think I'm getting closer to it. It seems to only be cutting the image when viewing with dual display monitors! So bizzare